# How do I write an Expression that will filter an Entity with an empty to-many relationship?

Tags: apache-cayenne

I have the following structure:

`Invoice` <->> `LineItem`

How do I write an Expression that will query the database for all the `Invoice` objects that do not have any related `LineItem` objects?

There is no `Invoice.LINE_ITEMS.isEmpty()` and `Invoice.LINE_ITEMS.isNull()` will not work because `myInvoice.getlineItems()` will return an empty collection not `null`.

Answer (score 2):

If you do an outer join using the null check should work. Write your expression like this:

> Invoice.LINE_ITEMS.outer().isNull()

Comment: Not exactly intuitive, but does seem to work. I feel a pull request coming on.

Comment: Also, does not appear to work in-memory. Only when querying the database.